# Imputing NAN values by pandas forward fill method with set pattern

Tags: pandas, dataframe

Suppose I am working on a Dataset where there is a column name "F_N" containing numeric values in a sequence like 10, 20, 30, nan, 50, nan, 70. Here I want these null places to fill by 40, and 60 in the respective place with pandas' help. I am aware of fillna(method=ffill), but it will give us 30 and 50 exact values, not patterns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use linear interpolation with `interpolate`:

```
df['F_N'] = df['F_N'].interpolate()
```

```
>>> df
    F_N
0  10.0
1  20.0
2  30.0
3  40.0
4  50.0
5  60.0
6  70.0
```

Comment: df['F_N] = df.F_N.interpolate() <<-- Thanks Sir I got this with your help.

Answer (score 0):

You describe a sequence with missing values.  [fillna()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) can take a series.  Hence simplest is to fill with expected values.  Code below demonstrates this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({"F_N":range(0,101,10)})
df.loc[np.random.choice(df.index,5)] = np.nan
df["fill"] = df["F_N"].fillna(pd.Series(range(0,101,10)))
```

#### output

|  | F_N | fill |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | nan | 0 |
| 1 | 10 | 10 |
| 2 | 20 | 20 |
| 3 | 30 | 30 |
| 4 | nan | 40 |
| 5 | nan | 50 |
| 6 | 60 | 60 |
| 7 | 70 | 70 |
| 8 | nan | 80 |
| 9 | 90 | 90 |
| 10 | 100 | 100 |